# jQuery - How to scroll the page to a div if div dynamically moves?

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, move, offset

Currently I am creating a website mainly using a mix of PHP, SQL, and JS. I use the JS to dynamically pull up new data using PHP and SQL. The current issue I am running into is that I have a button that when clicked will have the page scroll to the current DIV every 2.5 seconds based on offset. The issue is the function does not find the NEW offset once the element has moved.

**Code snippets:**

...

```
$(".button").click(function() {
            $message_focus = "TRUE";
            $to_focus=($(".focus_on_this").offset().top);
        });
```

...

```
if ($message_focus = "TRUE") {
        $("html, body" ).animate( { scrollTop: ($to_focus) },{ queue:false, duration:750 } );
    }
```

...

That is where the main issue is. It all works fine, though it only goes to the initial div's starting location. Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: You have not shown your code that "will have the page scroll to the current DIV every 2.5 seconds based on offset". You'll need to `setInterval` for that. Can you show the code you're using? The problem might be in that snippet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to recalculate `.focus_on_this`'s position everytime you scroll the page:

```
var $message_focus = false;

$(".button").click(function() {
    $message_focus = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if ($message_focus == true) {
        $("html, body" ).animate({
            scrollTop: $(".focus_on_this").offset().top
        },{
            queue:false,
            duration:750
        });
    }
}, 2500);
```

Answer (score 0):

How does the `div` dynamically moves? Is there any event which causes it to move? If yes then we need to set `$to_focus=($(".focus_on_this").offset().top);` every time this event is triggered. Only setting it on click will not work.

In the question you have mentioned on button click the page scrolls to the div every 2.5 seconds but I dont see any such code. You should use setInterval if you want to call any code repititively after a certain period as below.

```
setInterval(function(){
   //Do something after every 2000 milliseconds

}, 2000);
```